# Кэширование - простой класс

Tags: кэширование, mysql

Всем привет. Посоветуйте php классы для Кэширования.
Для сайта, который первый раз запустится. Я думал перед запуском не делать кеширование, но запросов довольна много, поэтому на первое время нужно какой-нибудь удобный, но простой класс кеширования. В дальнейшем буду использовать memCached, но пока что технические ресурсы не позволяют. Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мой файловый кэш, сделал на виртуальном хостинге. Библиотека фреймворка CodeIgniter, суть проста, в случае ООП можно поменять путь и использовать.

```
<?php
class Cache{
    private $_cacheFolder;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->_cacheFolder = 'app/cache/';
    }

    /**
    * чтение
    * 
    * @param mixed $key
    */
    public function load($key){
        $file = $this->_cacheFolder . md5($key);
        if(file_exists($file)){
            $data = unserialize(file_get_contents($file));
            if(time() <= $data['time'] + $data['ttl']){
                return $data['data'];
            }
            unlink($file);
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
    * добавление
    * 
    * @param mixed $key
    * @param mixed $data
    * @param mixed $time
    */
    public function save($key, $data, $time){
        $file = $this->_cacheFolder . md5($key);
        $content['data'] = $data;
        $content['time'] = time();
        $content['ttl'] = $time;
        if(file_put_contents($file, serialize($content))){
            @chmod($file, 0777);
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
    * удаление 
    * 
    * @param mixed $key
    */
    public function remove($key){
        $file = $this->_cacheFolder . md5($key);
        if(file_exists($file)){
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз у меня тоже фреймворк CI. Просто супер.

Comment: Так там же есть стандартный, чем не устраивает?

У меня просто с правами на файлы что-то было, поэтому сделал свой.

Comment: Стандартый кэширует всю страницу - это ни к чему хорошему не приводит.

Comment: как раз таки кеширование всей страницы приводит к быстрому ответу от сервака, нежели, генерить часть кода а остальную часть кода брать из кеша, смысл в таком виде кеширования?

Стандартный работает нормально и быстро.

Смысл в кешировании части страницы? если вывод на ней одинаковый, вы что запрос закешируете что страницу, от этого суть не поменяется, добавится только дополнительная проверка, которая как раз таки ни к чему!

Comment: К сожалению мой сайт через чур динамичный, скорее это приложение, система (не знаю как назвать...). Лучше всего будет делать блочно. Так как если брать в оборот всю страницу, то очень много будет действий с кешем - что он есть, что и нет. В моем случает так.

Comment: Так нужно ли кеширование тогда?

Вы не путайте кеширование запросов с кещированием страницы! Это разные вещи! Так что я думаю вопрос нужно поставить правильно.

С учетом последнего коммента я понимаю что кеш вам вообще не нужен!

А делать на сайте что-то ради галочки ИМХО неразумно!

Comment: Запустил сайт на хосте и потестил. Использовал класс представленный выше. Кешировал все что выводилось очень часто из базы, но не совсем динамично обновлялась. Заметил, что кеш увеличил скорость загрузки страницы.

Comment: Мне нужно было кэшировать только запросы из базы, для этого и написал библиотеку.